# Why isn't value of my variable updated after every multiplication?

Tags: java, immutability

Why isn't value of my variable `poc` updated after every multiplication done within `System.out.println();`?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte poc = 0b0001;

    System.out.println("The value of byte " + poc + " when multiplied by 0010 is: " + poc*0b0010);
    System.out.println("The value of byte " + poc + " when multiplied by 0010 is: " + poc*0b0010);
    System.out.println("The value of byte " + poc + " when multiplied by 0010 is: " + poc*0b0010);
    System.out.println("The value of byte " + poc + " when multiplied by 0010 is: " + poc*0b0010);
    System.out.println("The value of byte " + poc + " when multiplied by 0010 is: " + poc*0b0010);
    System.out.println("The value of byte " + poc + " when multiplied by 0010 is: " + poc*0b0010);
    System.out.println("The value of byte " + poc + " when multiplied by 0010 is: " + poc*0b0010);
    System.out.println("The value of byte " + poc + " when multiplied by 0010 is: " + poc*0b0010);
}
```

p.s. This is not homework. I'm new to Java, and I'm trying to grasp the concept of pass by value. I do not understand why isn't value of `poc` updated every time it is multiplied within `println` statement. For example, in the following code variable `poc` is updated every time.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte poc = 0b0001;

        System.out.println("The value of byte " + poc + " when incremented by 1 is: " + ++poc);
        System.out.println("The value of byte " + poc + " when incremented by 1 is: " + ++poc);
        System.out.println("The value of byte " + poc + " when incremented by 1 is: " + ++poc);
        System.out.println("The value of byte " + poc + " when incremented by 1 is: " + ++poc);
        System.out.println("The value of byte " + poc + " when incremented by 1 is: " + ++poc);
        System.out.println("The value of byte " + poc + " when incremented by 1 is: " + ++poc);
        System.out.println("The value of byte " + poc + " when incremented by 1 is: " + ++poc);
        System.out.println("The value of byte " + poc + " when incremented by 1 is: " + ++poc);
    }
```

Why is updated in the second piece of code, but not in the first one?

Comment: Why would it be updated? You've just got an expression `poc*0b0010` - why would you expect that to change the value of `poc`? There's nothing related to parameter passing here - it's just a matter of the expression `x * y` not changing either `x` or `y`...

Comment: What do you think `*` does? What do you think `++` does? Why do you think so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*This really has nothing  to do with pass-by-value <sup>†</sup>*

`poc*0b0010` is not a statement that assigns the result of `poc*0b0010` to `poc`, it is just an expression which returns the result of the multiplication.

`++poc` is an expression that both increments `poc` (assignment) and returns the result of the assignment.

Note that you can use `*=` ([a compound assignment operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2)) to do this by surrounding `poc*0b0010` in brackets to create a [*Parenthesized Expression*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.5) within the string concatenation:

```
System.out.println("The value of byte " + poc 
  + " when multiplied by 0010 is: " + (poc*=0b0010));
```

See [The Java Tutorials > Assignment, Arithmetic, and Unary Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) for a full tutorial of arithmetic and assignment.

Also see [JLS: 15.15.1. Prefix Increment Operator ++](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.1) and [15.17.1. Multiplication Operator *](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.1)

<sup>†</sup> *for information about pass-by-value see the section "Passing Primitive Data Type Arguments" in [this java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)*

Comment: I've tried using poc*=0b0010 withing `System.out.println()`, but I can't compile. Does that mean that other than variable++, I can't assign value to a variable within `System.out.println()`?

Comment: @KrausVonKraken, I was just creating the edit to show you how to do this - I had to find the reference in the JLS to compound assignment operators

Comment: Aha! It works now, so I have to use parentheses. Thank you.

Comment: @KrausVonKraken. Yes. See: [JLS 15.8.5. Parenthesized Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.5)

Answer (score 1):

The reason that this is happening is because `poc*0b0010` only returns a value, while `++poc` increments the value of `poc` AND then returns the updated value of `poc`.

Essentially `++poc` is the shorthand for `poc = poc + 1;`  Notice how the result of `poc + 1` is assigned to poc.

However, `poc*0b0010` is just arithmetic being performed & returned, but not assigned to anything.

If you used `poc *= 0b0010` then the expression would be equivalent to `poc = poc * 0b0010`.

Just a final note:  This behavior doesn't actually have anything to do with pass-by-value vs pass-by-reference, but instead has to do with assignment and the difference between arithmetic and unary operations.

Comment: If i use `poc*0b0010` withing print statement, I get compile error: unexpected type. I suppose I can't really use `System.out.println` to assign values. (other then variable++ assignment)

Comment: You can, however the result of `poc*0b0010` is not a string, which is what the method signature requires.  If you wrapped the operation in something like `System.out.println(Integer.toString(poc*0b0010))` then it would work.